# How do I get a Taxpayer Identification number for Google wallet merchant account while I am in India?

Tags: taxes, india

I am 18 years old. I want to publish an app on Google Play. I am from India. I don't have any tax identification number. Would you please tell me what is the procedure for me to follow. Please do mention if there are any other alternatives.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number#India

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter the PAN number. If you don't have one, get it by applying with Income Tax department India